# How to retrieve column value of sql server 2005 table and store it in label.Text of c# ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005

My question is

Suppose I have a Column "fname" whose value is 'Nikhil' in table "profile".

How to retrieve column value of sql server table and store it in label.Text of c# ASP.Net.

I mean what should be the code if I want label text to be "fname" value that is "Nikhil"

Connection is already done properly because I am able to display table data in Gridview
but not able to display it in label.

I had also seached but not understood the answer

label1.Text = ?; // I want fname here

Regards,

Nikhil

Comment: Did either of the answers below help you out?

Comment: Not Exactly but I figured it out !!!

Comment: I figured this :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909924/how-to-retrieve-column-value-of-sql-server-table-and-store-it-in-label-text-of-c

Comment: Haha, that is exactly what my answer below says =) [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6956439/how-to-retrieve-column-value-of-sql-server-2005-table-and-store-it-in-label-text/6956605#6956605)

Comment: Haha ! Thanks for your effort jadarnel27.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that Your query needs to be whatever it is to get the proper name

```
String fname = ""
// Create a new SqlCommand with your query to get the proper name and the connection string
SqlCommand getFnameCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 fname FROM profile ORDER BY fname DESC;", New SqlClient.SqlConnection"Your Connection String"))
getFnameCommand.Connection.Open() // Open the SqlConnection
fname = getFnameCommand.ExecuteScalar() // This pulls the result from the first column of the first row of your query result
getFnameCommand.Connection.Close() //Close the SqlConnection
label1.text=fname; //Set your label text to the data you just pulled
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a data in a table dtData
then you can use this code.
`int rowindex = 0;`
`Label1.Text=dtData.Rows[rowindex]["column name"].ToString();`

and from grid view use this code
`Label1.Text = GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text`
Cell is the column in the grid view